# Seaborn jointplot color histogram

Tags: python, seaborn, jointplot, histplot

I'd like to color my histogram according to my palette. Here's the code I used to make this, and here's the error I received when I tried an answer I found on here.

```
g = sns.jointplot(data=emb_df, x='f0', y='y', kind="hist", hue='klabels', palette='tab10', marginal_kws={'hist_kws': {'palette': 'tab10'}})
plt.show()
```

```
 UserWarning: The marginal plotting function has changed to `histplot`, which does not accept the following argument(s): hist_kws.
```

[image]

I have also tried this:

```
plt.setp(g.ax_marg_y.patches, color='grey')
```

But this does not color my histogram according my 'klabels' parameter, just a flat grey.

[image]

Comment: @JohanC thank you johan. If possible- do you have a similarly straightforward solution for plotting these side by side as subplots? Either way- feel free to make this an answer so that I may accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The marginal plot is colored by default using the same palette with corresponding hue. So, you could just run it without `marginal_kws=`. The `marginal_kws=` go directly to the `histplot`; instead of `marginal_kws={'hist_kws': {'palette': 'tab10'}}`, the correct use would be `marginal_kws={'palette': 'tab10'}`. If you would like stacked bars, you could try `marginal_kws={'multiple': 'stack'})`

If you want the marginal plots to be larger, the `ratio=` parameter can be altered. The default is `5`, meaning the central plot is 5 times as large as the marginal plots.

Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.jointplot(data=iris, x='petal_length', y='sepal_length', kind="hist", hue='species', palette='tab10',
                  ratio=2, marginal_kws={'multiple': 'stack'})
sns.move_legend(g.ax_joint, loc='upper left') # optionally move the legend; seaborn >= 0.11.2 needed
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.jointplot with histograms]

To have these plots side-by-side as subplots, you can call the underlying `sns.histplot` either with both `x=` and `y=` filled in (2D histogram), only `x=` given (horizontal histogram) or only `y=` given (vertical histogram).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 4))
sns.histplot(data=iris, x='petal_length', y='sepal_length', hue='species', palette='tab10', legend=False, ax=ax1)
sns.histplot(data=iris, x='petal_length', hue='species', palette='tab10', multiple='stack', legend=False, ax=ax2)
sns.histplot(data=iris, y='sepal_length', hue='species', palette='tab10', multiple='stack', ax=ax3)
sns.move_legend(ax3, bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.01], loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: jointplot as separate subplots]