# For a jointplot marginal plot can I use percentage to show in every item (color, hue )?

Tags: python, seaborn, jointplot

I think default is counts, but if I have 2+dimensions with different sample size, see the attachment image. How to make that distribution for each Name, individually?
Since quite different sample size hard to tell anything.percentile would be better.

[image: this is it]

my code:

```py
#import 
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
Faker = Faker('En-US')
Name = Faker.name()

#Crate fake data
m1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':Name,'X':[np.random.normal(3,100) for i in range(1000)],'Y':[np.random.normal(7,100) for i in range(1000)]})
m2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':Faker.name(),'X':[np.random.normal(50,20) for i in range(50)],'Y':[np.random.normal(-10,100) for i in range(50)]})
df = pd.concat([m1,m2])
sns.jointplot(data=df,x='X',y='Y',hue='Name')
```

let me know if this is clear please.
I'm a beginner.
[image]

Comment: The curve can't show counts not percentages without putting values into bins, as happens with a histogram. The curves are normalized such that the total *area* is 1. Note that by default, seaborn assumes `common_norm=True`, so scaling down both curves such that their summed area is 1.  With `common_norm=False` both curves would be scaled independently so that each individual area would be 1.  Could you further clarify what exactly is needed?

Comment: You would need histplot with percent in the margins. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63373194/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35920885/7758804

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69723626/7758804